# Python - how to send IP address to PHP?

Tags: php, python, zend-framework

Why isn't Python sending the IP address to PHP? Python always telling me that result=fail instead of `OK - working`

**Python:**

```
import requests;
r = requests.post('https://stackoverflow.com/unittest', data = { 'test' : 'test' } ); 
r.content;
// fail
```

**PHP:**

```
  public static function getRealIpAddr() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
  }  


  public function unittestAction() {
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $data = (object) $post;  
    $db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();


    $request_IP = self::getRealIpAddr();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sh_av_site_iptable` WHERE  ip='{$request_IP}' limit 1";    
    $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
    if (count($result) > 0) {      
    } 
    else {
      $json  = array( 
        'result' => 'fail',
        'reason' => '???? i dont know your IP, get out of my door, thank you spammer ????'
      );  
      $content = Zend_Json::encode($json);
      $this->getResponse()
              ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
              ->setBody($content)
              ->sendResponse();
      exit;
    } 

    echo "OK - working";
    exit;

   }
```

Comment: echo or print_r out all of the methods and see what you get. I find it hard to believe that none of them work, but it's possible

Comment: You can echo the sql statement and then run it in PhpMyAdmin or Mysql console. Also echo the ip address and check if it matches the ip address of the user